# reassign control detach ngcontrol directive

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I use directive with ngControl.valueChanges subscription. When I reassign form control (or parent form of this control) subscription destroyed.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhdcfd
Open console and pass some value to input. Subscription is working as well. After 5 secs timesout reassign to control to "321" - subscription in directive stops working.

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[customControl]' })
export class CustomControlDirective {

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="form">
<input formControlName="foo" customControl />
</form>`
})
export class AppComponent  {

  form = new FormGroup({
    foo: new FormControl("123")
  });


  ngOnInit() {  
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.form = new FormGroup({
          foo: new FormControl("321")
      });
    }, 5000)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `patchValue` or `setValue` to set the new values of the form:

```
  ngOnInit() {  
    setTimeout(() => {
      /*this.form = new FormGroup({
          foo: new FormControl("321")
      });*/
      // instead patchValue() or setValue()
      this.form.patchValue({ foo: "321" });
    }, 5000)
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjxhkj

**Update**

Based on your comment perhaps you could subscribe to the `valueChanges` when you create a new `FormControl`:

```
  ngOnInit() {  
    setTimeout(() => {
      const control = new FormControl("321");
      control.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
      this.form = new FormGroup({
          foo: control
      });
    }, 5000)
  }
```

I updated the Stackblitz.

Comment: In my case it is very difficult. I have recursive form with items with can have child items. All of them should have checkboxes. And list can add/update/remove items

`private fetchForm(positions: [], position?) {
    const fg = this.fb.group({ checked: false });

    if (positions) {
      fg.addControl("positions", this.fb.array(
        positions.map(p => this.fetchForm(p.positions, p))
      ));
    }

    if (position) {
      fg.addControl("position", this.fb.control(position));
    }

    return fg;
  }`